# Angular-NativeScript unknown HTML tags, properties (WebStorm)

Tags: angular, nativescript, webstorm

I've recently started a project in WebStorm making an Angular-NativeScript app, but I am getting errors on tags that should be recognized by NativeScript, as well as errors on attributes and properties.

I have the NativeScript plugin installed, and the app functions as expected when ran. The editor itself just doesn't seem to recognize these tags.

[image]

Is there anything I need to install that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Right, these warnings don't actually do anything. WebStorm just doesn't know 3rd party tags. There is an IntelliJ NativeScript plugin you can download (from in-app settings), and the tags will be recognized with it. Or just click add to custom HTML tags, as long as the tags actually work.